# Problema en el envío de un registro en CRUD Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, crud, laravel-8

Tengo un array con una lista de empresas y su localidad, ambas con sus tablas individuales. Las recorro  con un foreach, cada empresa tiene su enlace editar con la ruta correspondiente pero al momento de enviar, manda todos los registros de todas las empresas en vez de la que corresponde al boton.

Con el codigo queda mas claro :
**index.blade.php :**

```
       @foreach ($misEmpresas as $Empresa)
         <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="card card-widget widget-user-2">

              <div class="widget-user-header bg-warning">
                <h3 class="widget-user-username">{{$Empresa->nombre}}</h3> 
              </div>
  
              <div class="card-body">
              </div> 
              <div class="card-footer row">

                  <div class="col-md-6">
                       
                      <a  href="{{route('misempresas.edit',$Empresa)}}" class="btn btn-warning btn-block ">  Editar</a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                       <a   type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block "> Eliminar</a>
                  </div>

              </div>

            </div>
           </div>
       @endforeach
```

Al hacer clic en editar una empresa tomando de ejemplo la empresa con id=9 el controller recibe una colección de todas las empresas, como si en la vista anterior hubiese enviado la variable **$misEmpresas** en vez de la variable.

Puede que la funcion index tenga algo que ver por eso la publico, pero en el while me muestra correctamente las 4 empresas que tengo con el usuario logeado.

**$Empresas**
Controller :

```
public function index()
{
        $misEmpresas=Empresa::join('communes','communes.id','=','empresas.commune_id')
                              ->where('empresas.user_id',auth()->user()->id)
                              ->latest('empresas.id')
                              ->get();

        return view('empresas.misempresas',compact('misEmpresas'));
}

public function edit(Empresa $Empresa)
{
        // Return para comprobar los ratos recibidos  
        return $miEmpresa->all();

        $communes=Commune::orderBy('name','asc')->pluck('name','id');
        return view('empresas.edit',compact('Empresa','communes'));

}
 
** Ruta :**
```

Route::resource('misempresas',EmpresaController::class);

Comment: Muestranos tu ruta por favor

Comment: @BetaM Listo editado, Tambien agregué la funcion index que lista  las empresas que corresponden al usuario logeado, me muestra correctamente las empresas de ese usuario pero la  dejo de todas formas

Comment: puedes agregar todo el form? me interesa la parte de action y method, veo que no las pusiste

Answer (score 2, accepted):

la manera correcta en editar un dato es la siguiente

```
<a  href="{{route('misempresas.edit',$Empresa->id)}}" class="btn btn-warning btn-block ">  Editar</a>



 public function edit($Empresa_id){
            // Return para comprobar los ratos recibidos  
            //return $miEmpresa->all();
            $Empresa = Empresa::findOrFail($Empresa_id);
    
            return view('empresas.edit', ['empresa' => $Empresa]);
            //$communes=Commune::orderBy('name','asc')->pluck('name','id');
            //return view('empresas.edit',compact('Empresa','communes'));
    
    }
```

Comment: Lo resolvi gracias a esto, me explico. Me salia error ya que imprimia {{ $miEmpresa->all(); }}  y me arrojaba 9 registros, pero imprimi {{$miEmpresa}} y me  mostró el que necesitaba asi que genial !   gracias